# Else If Statements based on user's previous choice

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a .aspx file where I have code and here is the code where the user selects a drop down choice:

```
<td align="right">PI Organization: </td>
<td>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server" TabIndex="9" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddlOrg_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <asp:ListItem Value="none">(Select One)</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>University of Fun</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>UOFF</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

I need to right under it an if statement where if the user selects University of Fun of UOFF it would be $40 and if the user selected Other it would be $50

Here is what I have:

```
if(ddOrg="University of Fun"){
    fee = $40;
}
else {(ddlOrg="UOFF"){
    fee = $40;
}
else {ddOrg="Other"){
    fee = $50;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to update the .aspx page to show 40 or 50 when the drop down changes?

Comment: I'm assuming this is pseudo code?

Comment: Yes that is correct.
My if statements do not seem to be displaying the correct 40 or 50, rather just the statement.

Comment: Do you want to do this client-side using javascript?

Comment: Yes this will be on the front end side so that the user would see it before submitting.

Comment: this is .net - it shouldn't be tagged as Classic ASP

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend removing AutoPostBack="true" if you want to display a client side notification before the user submits.

I would also suggest having a value against each list item, for example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server" TabIndex="9" >
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">(Select One)</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">University of Fun</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">UOFF</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">Other</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

You could then display the message depending on the user's selection using jQuery/javascript.

In your .aspx view you could use something along the lines of the following:

```
<%--Reference jQuery--%>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#<%=ddlOrg.ClientID %>").change(function() {
             var selectedValue = parseInt($(this).val());

             //add extra logic for your options
             if (selectedValue === 1) {

                 //set the text to display
                 $("#priceNotice").html("$40");
             });
         });
     });
</script>

<span id="priceNotice"></span>
```

This would cause "$40" to display in the span if the user selected "University of Fun".  You could modify the code to satisfy your other options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the equality operator (==) instead of the assignment operator. Also, your first two cases can be condensed into one.

```
 if(ddOrg == "University of Fun" || ddlOrg == "UOFF"){
    fee = $40;
} else {
    fee = $50;
}
```

Also, you had some misplaced brackets and there is no need for a condition with the else. If you do need a condition you must use `elseif` not `else`. Else essentially means for all other cases, so it does not take a condition, it's the fall back if none the previous conditions are met. `||` is the logical operator or. Since the fee for both conditions in the `if` is $40, you may as well `if ( conditionOne OR conditionTwo)` to make the code more readable.